# How would you access 1st character of a text input in assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm a super beginner in assembly language so sorry if this is a noob question but I'm trying to validate a message that the user inputs. I want to check if the message begins with a capital. I'm wondering how to access the first character of my string? This is what I've done so far

```
lea         r10, [text + 1] //get first letter of "text"
cmp         r10, \"A\"      //compare w A
jl          invalid

cmp         r10, \"Z\"      //compare w Z
jg          invalid
```

Could someone please help me with this? Am I supposed to convert "text +1" into ASCII and then compare it to the ASCII values of A and Z? Also I'm not sure if I'm using lea correctly.

Comment: What's the problem with this piece of code?

Comment: The first letter will be at position `[txt]` and not `[txt + 1]`.

Comment: Why are you using `\"A\"` with backslash escapes?  Is this actually GNU C inline asm (.intel_syntax noprefix) that goes inside a C double-quoted string?  If so, just use single quotes.  But that seems unlikely because GAS treats bare labels differently from NASM.

Comment: `cmp         r10, \"A\"` is comparing the pointer (which you put in a register with LEA), not the value at `byte [r10]`.

Comment: I'm also curious what the syscall is about. What OS are you on?

Comment: Would be helpful if you gave us an example of something that can actually be assembled and executed.

Comment: @PickleRick: good question.  On x86-64 Linux, rax=1 / `syscall` is `write`, not `read`.  (`__NR_read` is 0 in `/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h`).  And `edi=1` is fd=stdout.  x86-64 MacOS uses syscall numbers with a high bit set, and Windows doesn't document direct use of `syscall`, only the DLL interface.  So it's likely supposed to be Linux.  OP should use `strace ./my_program` to see what syscalls they actually make.